# Does naive bayes classifier perform text annotation?

Tags: text-processing, information-extraction

Does naive bayes classifier perform text annotation (sequence tagging)?
If yes, i need a tutorial please.
What do you think about MALLET for naive baies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naive Bayes is a form of classifier that makes a prediction about one variable, for example a label for a document. In a sequence tagging problem, you are making predictions about a sequence of variables: one for each token.

You can do this by treating each token as its own independent classification problem, or you can use a model that makes predictions for the whole sequence jointly, with the decision for one token affecting the decision for neighboring tokens.

The sequence equivalent for Naive Bayes is a Hidden Markov Model. An equivalent classifier/sequence-tagger pair is logistic regression and conditional random fields (CRFs). Mallet implements all of these, as do many other systems.